# Email Templates With Variables

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using code, written with help from this forum, to select a .oft email template from a central repository via a drop down menu.

```
Public Sub Email_Templates()

  With Select_Email_Template
    .Show
    If .Tag <> -1 Then
      CreateItemFromTemplate(Templates(.Tag, FullPath:=True)).Display ' Templates(.Tag) also works
    End If
  End With
  Unload Select_Email_Template

End Sub

Public Function Templates _
                ( _
                  Optional ByVal plngIndex As Long = -1 _
                , Optional ByVal NameOnly As Boolean = False _
                , Optional ByVal FullPath As Boolean = False _
                ) As Variant

  Const strcTemplatesDir As String = "\\c\s\caf1\Digital Delivery Group\DDCOPS\Splunk\Email Templates\"
  Const strcTemplateExtension As String = ".oft"

  Static avarTemplateNames As Variant

  If IsEmpty(avarTemplateNames) Then
    avarTemplateNames = Array _
    ( _
      "Account Amendment Non SC" _
    , "Amendment SC Application Received" _
    , "Amendment SC" _
    , "Creation Non SC" _
    , "Account Creation SC Application Received" _
    , "Account Creation SC" _
    , "Export Function" _
    , "Password Reset" _
    )
  End If
  If plngIndex <> -1 Then
    If NameOnly = True And FullPath = False Then
      Templates = avarTemplateNames(plngIndex)
    Else
      Templates = strcTemplatesDir & avarTemplateNames(plngIndex) & strcTemplateExtension
    End If
  Else
    Templates = avarTemplateNames
  End If

End Function
```

This is an example of a template:

> Hi ,
>
> I have been asked to create Splunk account(s) for you in the following
>   environment(s).
>
> Your username and password details are:
>
> Username:  Password:
>
> Many thanks and kind regards

I'd like to dynamically add the username and password pre the creation of the email.

I really don't want to 'hard code' the email content in the VBA code  because these templates are used by multiple users so if changes need to be made to them these would have to changed multiple times.

Any advice on the best way forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the values and replace unique placeholders like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub userpass()

Dim userName As String
Dim userPassword As String

userName = "someBody"
userPassword = "easilyBroken"

MyTemplate userName, userPassword

End Sub

Private Sub MyTemplate(uName, uPword)

Dim msg As mailitem

' Template with unique text "Username:" and "Password:"
Set msg = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Test\Account Creation SC.oft")

With msg
    .body = Replace(.body, "Username:", "Username:" & uName)
    .body = Replace(.body, "Password:", "Password:" & uPword)
End With

msg.Display

End Sub
```